# Why do we use "War is horrific" but not "Wars are horrific"?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, abstract-nouns

I saw sentences like

> War **is** horrific… War **is** hell,…

I'm confused by that, I really appreciate if anyone could explain that for me.

And can I say “Dog is…” and when should I say that, instead of “Dogs are…”

Comment: What do you mean? "Wars are" is perfectly grammatical ([here](https://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2018/jul/9/trade-wars-are-bad-and-america-is-losing/)'s an example). Are you talking about something else?

Comment: I saw sentences like "War is horrific, War is hell, ..."

Comment: There's also the song *War* whose lyrics ask "War. What **is** it good for?"

Answer (score 1):

The word ***war*** can be used as either a countable or an uncountable noun, just like, to a lesser extent, the word ***sugar***.

Consider:

Uncountable:

> ***Sugar*** is a sweet, crystalline substance obtained mostly from
>   sugarcane.

Countable:

> Some tea, perhaps? How many ***sugars***?

Now let's examine ***war***:

Uncountable:

> ***War*** has been humanity's favorite entertainment since times immemorial.

Countable:

> Some of those Visigoths couldn't be bothered to contribute to anyone's
>   culture: they were busy fighting ***a war***.

Comment: And to extend that to the dog part of the question, 'dog' can be uncountable but has limited usage, probably because we are used to seeing dogs as individual animals bounding around.

Comment: "How many sugars?" is a product of ellipsis, it stands for "How many *teaspoons of* sugar?" Is there an ellipsis in the statement, "Wars are bad"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Well, you know. "How many acts of war ... " etc.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That particular usage is ellipsis (teaspoons, lumps, whatever unit you’re using), but others aren’t. In physics, there are different types of sugars, for example, just like there are different types of salts.